# Logic Circuits, drawing them

Tags: logic

[Prompt](http://puu.sh/lD7OS/4e496aca8f.png)

My question is twofold: I don't know any program/method of drawing these circuits, so I would love to know an easy way to draw them. The second question is: on 1), what is the best method of approaching these problems? do the parenthesis first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to start with everything in parentheses first, then go from there, but of course, this is not the only way to approach these problems. Is there any particular problem you have with drawing circuits? It really depends on the individual on how they would approach these problems.

This website is pretty good for drawing logic circuits. If your teacher is okay with the symbols, you can screenshot your work if necessary. Hope this helps!

http://logic.ly/demo/

Comment: Thank you. I want to draw these, but I don't know how to do it on the computer, I can only do it on paper, however my teacher wants this done on the computer. :(

Comment: Oh thank you for that website! I am actually unsure of how to do the first one haha, could you help me out on that one?

Comment: If you still need help, please leave a comment.